# How to programmatically create new revision and publish it?

Tags: 7, nodes

(I am using [Revisioning](https://www.drupal.org/project/revisioning).) I call `node_load(nid, vid)` (with the latest version id), give new values to some fields, and then save the node. Setting `$node->is_current = TRUE` before saving will ensure that this version of the node is now published. However, it does not create a new revision. So I try setting `$node->revision = TRUE` also, but this creates a new **unpublished** revision which is not what I would expect.

How can I edit a node, and save it as a new revision *and also as* the current published revision? Not sure if it is a bug in the module.

```
// Node has some new revisions since the version that is currently published.
$vid = revisioning_get_latest_revision_id($nid);
$node = node_load($nid, $vid);
$node->revision = TRUE;
$node->is_current = TRUE;
$node->status = 1;
node_save($node);
// New revision created, but not published.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it will work when you explicitly set `revision_moderation` to `FALSE`. If moderation is not required, it should be published right away.

```
$vid = revisioning_get_latest_revision_id($nid);
$node = node_load($nid, $vid);
$node->revision = TRUE;
$node->is_current = TRUE;
$node->status = 1;
$node->revision_moderation = FALSE;
node_save($node);
```

From the example here: http://drupalprogrammatically.com/anwsers/7/create-node

Poster of above url also sets `$node->revision = FALSE;`, but that would give me the impression no new revision is saved, which is not what you want.
I hope it helps.

Comment: This is the missing piece! Thank you for finding this!

Answer (score -1):

Too easy - just separate the steps. First set a new revision and save, then load it again and adjust the fields and set published and save.

Comment: This is not ideal and has become a performance issue. I'm updating a lot of nodes :/